How to call different function based on column value in dataframe in Pyspark?
I have a dataframe that contains column 1, column 2 and column 3, column 2 can have a version value like 1.0 or 2.0.
Based on this column, I need to process the dataframe columns. Something like:
if(column2 > 1.0)
      call method1()
else
      call method2()

This I have to do in Pyspark.
Tried searching for stuff online, but most talk about conditional column transformation, or using otherwise to decide column value, but I want to call the method to process the full data frame, not column, value.

think you have to add more information to this question, like dummy data for frame. with dataset input and expected output details

You can achieve it by the following sample code:
This is your data:
data = [
    Row(
        column1="foo",
        column2=1.0,
        column3=1,
    ),
    Row(
        column1="foo",
        column2=2.0,
        column3=1,
    ),
    Row(
        column1="foo",
        column2=3.0,
        column3=3,
    ),
]

schema = StructType([
    StructField(name="column1", dataType=StringType()),
    StructField(name="column2", dataType=DoubleType()),
    StructField(name="column3", dataType=IntegerType()),
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)


+-------+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3|
+-------+-------+-------+
|    foo|    1.0|      1|
|    foo|    2.0|      1|
|    foo|    3.0|      3|
+-------+-------+-------+

This is the logic:
def method1(df: DataFrame, col_name: str, descr: str) -> DataFrame:
    return df.withColumn(col_name, f.lit(descr))

def method2(df: DataFrame, col_name: str, value: int) -> DataFrame:
    return df.withColumn(col_name, f.lit(value))


rows = [{"column2": row.column2, "column3": row.column3} for row in df.select("column2", "column3").distinct().collect()]

df_new = df.limit(0)
for row in rows:
    val_col_2 = row["column2"]
    val_col_3 = row["column3"]

    if val_col_2 > 1.0 and val_col_3 == 1:
        df_tmp = (
            df.filter((f.col("column2") > 1.0) & (f.col("column3") == 1))
            .transform(method1, "col_name_first_cond", ">1.0 and col3 == 1")
        )
    elif val_col_2 > 2.0:
        df_tmp = (
            df.filter(f.col("column2") > 2.0)
            .transform(method1, "col_name_second_cond", ">2.0")
        )
    else:
        df_tmp = (
            df.filter(f.col("column2") == val_col_2)
            .transform(method2, "col_name_third_cond", 2)
        )
    df_new = df_new.unionByName(df_tmp, allowMissingColumns=True)

df_new = df.join(df_new, on=["column1", "column2", "column3"], how="left")

Output:
+-------+-------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|column1|column2|column3|col_name_third_cond|col_name_first_cond|col_name_second_cond|
+-------+-------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|    foo|    1.0|      1|                  2|               NULL|                NULL|
|    foo|    2.0|      1|               NULL| >1.0 and col3 == 1|                NULL|
|    foo|    3.0|      3|               NULL|               NULL|                >2.0|
+-------+-------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+


Thanks for the elaborated answer. But as i said i want to process full data frame differently based on column not just column transformation.

please provide an example. Add input data and expected output. The provided information are not enough to help you.
